# My path set isn't working when running java program in cmd

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am a beginner at batch file coding and have some experience with the command prompt.  I was looking up how to run a java program from a batch file and noticed that I needed to make a path so it could compile and run.  What is weird is that when i make the path, compile and run the code, it says that the javac isn't an internal or external command.  Can someone explain to me if there is a way that I can make a path using a USB?  The intention of my code is to copy over to the desktop,then run the program, and finally return the outputted program file.  I want to be able to run this on any windows computer.  Here is my code.  Thanks.  I have tried almost everything.

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\Users\%username%\Desktop 
mkdir HackerMan
echo d | xcopy /d /s %~d0 C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HackerMan
cd /d C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HackerMan\ProgramFiles
set path = "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HackerMan\ProgramFiles\Java\bin"
javac IPGrabber.java
java IPGrabber
copy /y C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HackerMan\ProgramFiles\ip_info.txt  %~d0\IPs\ip_info.txt 
cd /d C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
rmdir /s /q HackerMan
rmdir /s /q C:\$Recycle.Bin\HackerMan
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386697/why-is-no-string-output-with-echo-var-after-using-set-var-text-on-comman)

Comment: If you read the help file for the `SET` command you may notice that it never shows the usage syntax of having a space before or after the equals symbol.

Comment: One more hint: `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"` works even with user account name containing space characters and user profile directory being stored on a different drive and/or different directory. `%username%` should be used only for referencing the name of the user account, but `%USERPROFILE%` should be used on referencing the user's profile directory or one of its subdirectories. See also Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 2):

> set path = "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HackerMan\ProgramFiles\Java\bin"

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

**PATH** is the sequence of directories searched by windows to find an executable if it isn't found in the current directory. To change path, use `"set path=newdirectory;%path%"` which appends the current *path* to the new directory.